# codition statement empty or not empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Need help to see if the array is empty or not.
what are the condition block for this?

empty array look like this:

```
[
    {
        "readTime": "2019-09-09T15:20:44.648599Z"
    }
]
```

not empty array look like this:

```
[
    {
        "document": {
            "name": "projects/warrenty-MdBQxhFSQF11ZKImqL",
            "fields": {
                "plate": {
                    "stringValue": "AW69176"

                "createDate": {
                    "timestampValue": "2019-08-22T21:08:42.563Z"
                },
                "product": {
                    "stringValue": "Paint"
                },
                "exp_date": {
                    "timestampValue": "2026-08-22T21:08:18Z"
                }
            },
            "createTime": "2019-08-22T21:09:19.972639Z",
            "updateTime": "2019-09-09T11:33:27.134588Z"
        },
        "readTime": "2019-09-09T15:19:49.433613Z"
    },
]
```

Comment: that first array is not empty though? please post the results that you want or an attempt

Comment: `[
    {
        "readTime": "2019-09-09T15:20:44.648599Z"
    }
]` this is not empty array

Comment: Assign your collection to a variable and run `items.filter(({ document }) => document);`. This will only return objects where document returns a truthy value.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your JSON you can just check if each object's 'document' property exists.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i].document){
      //exists
    }
    else { //doesn't exist}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array using `forEach` and can use `hasOwnProperty` to check if the object have any key by name `document`

```js
let data = [{
  "document": {
    "name": "projects/warrenty-MdBQxhFSQF11ZKImqL",
    "fields": {
      "plate": {
        "stringValue": "AW69176",

        "createDate": {
          "timestampValue": "2019-08-22T21:08:42.563Z"
        },
        "product": {
          "stringValue": "Paint"
        },
        "exp_date": {
          "timestampValue": "2026-08-22T21:08:18Z"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2019-08-22T21:09:19.972639Z",
      "updateTime": "2019-09-09T11:33:27.134588Z"
    },
    "readTime": "2019-09-09T15:19:49.433613Z"
  }
}, {
  "readTime": "2019-09-09T15:19:49.433613Z"
}]

data.forEach((e, index) => {
  if (e.hasOwnProperty('document')) {
    console.log(`Object at index ${index} has document key`)
  } else {
    console.log(`Object at index ${index} does not have document key`)
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The "empty array" as you call it is not really empty as it contains an object. 
But I think what you want to do is figure out whether the array contains an object with the structure of the second array.

In order to check whether your array is "empty" as you call it, you can check wether your object has a property "document" or not.

```
function isEmpty(array){
 var object = array[0];
 return !object.hasOwnProperty('document'); 
}
```

This function will return true when your array is "empty", and false when it is not.